# How to display attachMany images in frontend in Octobercms?

Tags: laravel, twig, octobercms

This should be pretty straight forward but cant figure out what is missing. I am trying to display attachMany in front-end but it is not working.

It is working fine in the back-end and only works in the front-end when i change it to attachOne

```
    `{% for image in ads.gallery %}
   <img src="{{ image.gallery.thumb(100, auto) }}">
  {% endfor %}`
```

I expect it to display all the images uploaded in a front-end gallery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the relation **attachOne**, It is working because you are trying to get gallery even after using `for loop` via `{{ image.gallery.thumb(100, auto) }}`.

For **attachMany** relation, you will need to do something like this.

```
{% for image in ads.gallery %}
   <img src="{{ image.thumb(100, auto) }}">
{% endfor %}
```

For more information, visit this official documentation link [Here.](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/attachments#viewing-attachments)

And, if you have still any doubts, please comment.

**EDIT**

So you are using this query on the page,

```
$this['ads'] = Advert::whereHas('cats', function ($query) use ($slug) 
              { 
                 $query->where('slug',$slug); 
              })->get();
```

Now, based on your query, you are retrieving multiple ***ads*** on the page, So you will need to write one for loop for your ads to show on the page and on loop for gallery

```
{% for ad in ads %}
   //to get values from you can do {{ad.name}}
   //to get gallery values from particular ad, you will need to write for loop again(because you have used relation attachMany) 
    {% for image in ad.gallery %}
       <img src="{{ image.thumb(100, auto) }}">
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

And to retrieve gallery, you should use [eager loading](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/relations#eager-loading), So your query should be

```
$this['ads'] = Advert::with('gallery')->whereHas('cats', function ($query) use ($slug) 
              { 
                 $query->where('slug',$slug); 
              })->get();
```

Comment: Is there anything i am suppose to add to this because that is where i am pulling it from. `$this['ads'] = Advert::whereHas('cats', function ($query) use ($slug) {
                  $query->where('slug',$slug);
               })->get();
` no luck yet

Comment: @OsujiKingsley I got your confusions. I have edited my answer. Please understand it and try to resolve your problems.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove **gallery** from below code and it will work.

```
<img src="{{ image.thumb(100, auto) }}">
```